# Single query execution file through a function

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Please give me suggestion..

My purpose is to make a single query execution file that will execute all the query & return the result

like in .net

Answer (score 0):

[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) can do multi queries. `file_get_contents()` the file, and execute it using PDO.